# How to detect if a file is unavailable on iOS using cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

[Document picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmB0m.png) I cannot select a file from one drive when the file is not available (appears in the list but is not on the device)

I am trying to detect if the file is available to show a warning to the user but it only lets you do operations like renaming the file that fail with a network error.

I tried these methods but they do not return any error or warning using cordova@9.0.0 and cordova-ios@5.1.1

- cordova-plugin-chooser
- cordova-plugin-filepicker
- cordova-documentpicker
- an input type="file"